# Optimizing Listview - Viewholder vs CursorLoader

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-listview, performance

I am a novice in android programming. I am building an app in which my activity needs to query `ContactsProvider` and show the results in a `ListView`. I also want to implement search(filter) on results.

I have already implemented the view-holder pattern on my Custom BaseAdapter  for efficiency/user friendliness of the listview. Now I want to ask that do I need to use `CursorLoader` /`CursorAdapter` or continue with Custom Adapter.

**I simply want to ask which one is more efficient and user friendly among CursorLoader and Custom Adapter provided I implemented view-holder pattern?**

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/part_2_-_using_the_contacts_contentprovier/

Comment: I know it @PratikButani  and this is just a general question, so I suppose you do not need any code for this.